# ¿Como dividir en lenguaje ensamblador?

Tags: ensamblador

Estoy tratando de dividir un número entre 10 en lenguaje ensamblador, y no sé porque no me guarda el resultado en el registro `EAX`, les dejo el pedazo de código a ver si algo esta mal.

```
          _asm {
                mov eax, w    //w=123
                mov ebx, 10   
                div ebx       
                mov r,eax   
                
            }
```

Answer (score 7):

Cuando divide por un registro de 32 bits, el par de registros `EAX:EDX` (número de 64 bits) se divide por este registro. Por lo tanto, debe poner a cero el registro `EAX` y colocar el dividendo en `EDX`.

Ejemplo de código corregido:

```
_asm {
    xor eax, eax
    mov edx, w
    mov ecx, 10
    div ecx
    mov r, eax
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tenía el mismo problema, ya que en el registro `edx` donde se almacena el residuo tenía asignado un valor y como respuesta en `eax` me daba un valor diferente, lo solucioné asignando el valor 0 a `edx` antes de dividir.

Comment: Gracias por el aporte. Tal como está, se parece más a un comentario que a una respuesta, Si consideras que tu propuesta aporta mejor información o algo diferente a la respuesta existente, sería de mucha utilidad que nos mostraras el código.